# How to get jQuery sortable list order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery Sortable to allow users to drag and drop elements on the page. When a user drags a div I need to get the updated order of the list and pass it to the back end. So far I've tried:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                    data: oData,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/url/here'
            });
    }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

but this makes the animation really not smooth and alerts no data. How do I get a position list every time a user drags and drops a div?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinabraham/7rbv20yd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `refreshPositions()` function you can use that returns a object representing the sortable item. You can then obtain the updated list of children by making a call to `.children()` on that object.

Save the positions to a variable in the `stop` event, which is triggered after you have finished sorting.

I've updated your function to include the `stop` event:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  stop: function(ev, ui) {
    //Get the updated positions by calling refreshPositions and then .children on the resulting object.
    var children = $('#sortable').sortable('refreshPositions').children();
    console.log('Positions: ');
    //Loopp through each item in the children array and print out the text.
    $.each(children, function() {
        console.log($(this).text().trim());
    });
  }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/7rbv20yd/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use the `toArray()` method, detailed here: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

Comment: Thanks @Sterling for you answer. Tried that still the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinabraham/7rbv20yd/1/

Comment: In your fiddle, you need to call the toArray method on the sortable, so `$( "#sortable" ).sortable("toArray")` Also, the items that are being sorted, which are the `li`s don't have ids. The immediate children of the sortable need to have ids in order to use `toArray`